# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore Security & Encryption for storing sensitive data

Tags: iphone, icloud

I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to store player data for my game on iCloud.

- Can iCloud users modify these values without my knowledge/permission, thus "hacking" the game?
- If so, should I encrypt the data before storing it?
- If so, what encryption schema would you recommend, and would I need to set the "uses encryption" flag when submitting to Apple?

Comment: Lots of hacking of Game Center going on, Apple doesn't care either. I wouldn't worry too much about score hacking, really, GameCenter or not. Of the few that care to do it, you can't stop the ones that are intent on doing it, sadly. People do it by modifying the outbound HTTP with a proxy. Even SSL stuff can be tampered with. If you're encrypting first it could help, and I don't think you'd need to notify Apple that you're doing anything :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article: You should be safe

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html

Hey I made a comment up there but wanted to point out...iCloud != Game Center.  The point of Game Center is that "other players" can see scores. iCloud is one user only, and will only see his own scores. So other people can't go into User A's iCloud sandbox and get his data out of it.

If you're using iCloud to store game scores, what's the hurt on if they modify it. Devil's advocate, sorry :-)

Also edit:

Read an article not too long ago about an aspiring young dev who was tinkering with the GameCenter SDK and came up with some good hacks for jailbreakers, that could intercept or forge outgoing GameCenter stuff. Not much you can do about that, really.  I mean, can't encrypt the data you're sending to GameCenter, it's got to be sent in the raw

Comment: I'm very aware of the differences and limitations of both iCloud and Game Center. I am not using this for storing scores, etc. Suffice to say that iCloud is the right choice for the particular data I am storing. Unfortunately, this did not answer my question. Obviously I know that User B can't access User A's data. My question is if User A can manually edit his own data outside my application.

Comment: Let me also point out that you assumed that I was talking about storing scores. This is not correct. I'm talking about storing sensitive user-specific metadata applicable to my game. If they modified this data, it would have dire consequences, since it is a multiplayer game and they would gain a huge advantage.

Comment: To get the keyValueStore don't you need to provide the correct entitlements, which need a cert? For this reason, non-Sandboxed Mac Apps can't use iCloud...they can't get the proper entitlements to access the keyStore

Comment: Ah, I see, multiplayer. So the stakes are high. The thing about encryption though, is that you have to figure out what key you're encrypting with. Can't use UDID because of people with multiple devices. The public UDID is also not guaranteed to be the same either.

Comment: My thought for encryption would be to use a hash of the GameKit's playerID. This way, the iCloud game metadata only works (decrypts) if it matches the same player who created it.

Comment: see my edit. Per apple docs, users are never interacting with items on iCloud directly. They make a special request to Apple's iCloud API and the content is returned. Encryption is handled by Apple themselves. Just one more thing though. Never underestimate the lengths people will go through to disrupt and troll other people. These API calls can still be intercepted with a proxy.

Comment: So, I understand that data is transmitted securely & encrypted on the cloud. However, can I be guaranteed that **only** my app can access and decrypt the data? I guess what I'm asking is if there's any app out there that lets users arbitrarily modify their own iCloud data for different apps. From Apple's perspective, I don't think this would be bad, because the user "owns" the data. But to me, this is very bad because I am storing sensitive metadata.